# How can a highstock annotation be deleted by pressing the delete key, and edited by pressing the enter key?

Tags: highcharts

Is there a way to bind the "remove annotation" function that is typically activated by a 'mousedown' action on the delete icon to the `delete` key on a keyboard?

And similarly, can the "edit annotation" function be binded to the `enter` key on the keyboard? Image below for reference.

[image]

Appreciate the help of anyone kind enough to answer this.

Comment: Not direct from API but I need to see your code, could you show live demo?

Comment: Thanks for the note. Can we use the Highstocks custom GUI demo as reference? https://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/library/pure/highcharts/highcharts/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/stock-tools-custom-gui


I'm doing some customizations in my code which would sharing it confusing, but would love to know how this could be done using the Highcharts default demo as an example. Thanks!

Comment: I think you need to add some keyboard event `function addPopupEvents(chart)` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent